# Using ...rest ES6 put argument in strange order

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

in nodeJS i write:

```
path = 'public/MIN-1234';
path = path.split('/');
return path.join( process.cwd(), ...path);
```

I expect to :

```
  c:\CODE\public/MIN-1234
```

but got:

```
 `‌publicC:\CODEMIN-1234`
```

what??

Comment: You're overwriting the module `path` with your variable. Friendly hint: always use `const` with requires.

Comment: Georg is correct - you're trying to call the [Node.js `path.join` function](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_paths), but you're actually just calling [`Array.prototype.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) on your split path.

Comment: @abhishekkannojia You're thinking of `Array.join`, not `path.join`.

Comment: What is ec6? I've seen that a few times but still don't know.

Comment: right !!! nice thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments under your question provide some valuable guidance for something you are doing incorrectly. Specifically you seem to think you're using node's `path.join` (where `path` is a node module and `path.join` is a valid module method) when in fact you've overwritten `path` with your path addition string and then converted the string to an array which, misleadingly, also has a `join` method with completely different functionality.

However, there also seems to be a further issue with your attempt to use ECMAScript 2015 (which is sometimes abbreviated as ES6 but never EC6) rest spread syntax with node's `path.join` method.

If you've had a previously valid reason to split your path addition at its dividers, then you can use ES6 rest spread to add these elements to the path:

```
function something() {
  const path = require('path');
  const myPathAddition = 'public/MIN-1234';
  const myPathAdditionElmts = myPathAddition.split('/'); // if you really need to do this anyway
  return path.join(process.cwd(), ...myPathAdditionElmts);
}
```

However, if you've had no other reason to split your path addition, then don't bother splitting it just to immediately re-join the resulting segments in the `path.join` call. Instead, you can just join the "un-split" original string without the need to use spread syntax:

```
function something() {
  const path = require('path');
  const myPathAddition = 'public/MIN-1234'; // don't bother splitting this
  return path.join(process.cwd(), myPathAddition); // just join it as is
}
```

Note: This solution works fine in my Mac terminal. If you're doing this on a Windows machine and really need to work with both back-slashes and forward-slashes in your path segments as you suggested in your question, then you may want or need to do more parsing than I've shown to ensure valid/consistent/clear path syntax. However, the general concept I've demonstrated with respect to the need, or lack thereof, for using spread syntax with `path.join` remains valid.

Comment: tanks, the reason for using `path.join` in the first time is to join the path cross OS correctly (windows,linux)